# Как выбрать строки НЕ заканчивающиеся на "|"

Tags: регулярные-выражения

Подскажите как выбрать строки НЕ заканчивающиеся на "|" ?
пробовал так:  `^.*?[^|]$`
неполучается, вместе с нужной строкой выделяются также все строки идущие перед ней

Comment: Реализация какая регулярных выражений? В pcre Ваш шаблон корректно работает, предшествующие строки не выделяются вместе с искомой — https://regex101.com/r/dN3tE9/1 . Спасибо.

Comment: в блокноте akelpad

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Отбой , в блокноте Akelpad была отмечена галка "захватывать \n"